# PHP WordPress - How to replace with image the "Featured" text in sticky post?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I'm using Twenty-Sixteen theme as a child theme and I want to delete that "Featured" line of text under a sticky post and replace it with an image on the same place.

I've tried to edit this by deleting `'Featured'` text block in **content.php** but then everything disappears when I preview my page.

What do you think, what should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't delete `'featured'` thats actually a part of the theme and it breaks. You should **add or edit entries within sections, but never delete sections themselves**. Can you paste the `'featured'` block of code here so we see?

Comment: Here are those lines from content.php where I've tried to delete ,Featured'.  <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
   <span class="sticky-post"><?php _e( 'Featured', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found solution.

This:

```
<?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
            <span class="sticky-post"><a href="<?php _e( 'javascript:void(0)', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="/sticky_pin.png"> </a></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Instead of this:

```
<?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?> 
            <span class="sticky-post"><?php _e( 'Featured', 'twentysixteen' );></span> 
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This would definitely work!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.sticky-post').hide();
});
```

or

```
<?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?> <span class="sticky-post"><?php // _e( 'Featured', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></span> <?php endif; ?>
```

or

```
<?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?> <span class="sticky-post" style="display:none"><?php _e( 'Featured', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></span> <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thats not the way you do

Comment: Hey Bilal, thanks. Site is currently running just on local machine. I've tried to edit something with CSS and it give me results but still FEATURED text stays.